# Implementation of Logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

In the beginning, I am Japanese and not good at English, so my sentence may be incorrect. Sorry.
I made the code that is about logistic regression.
And I tested this code with dataset, but it is not appropriate rate.
That's why there is any mistakes in this code. If so, please let me know.
Moreover, I want to know the way to plot data and decision boundary.

```
class logisticr(object):

def __init__(self, eta=0.01):
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import random
    self.eta = eta

def sigFunc(self, z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp( -z ))

def predict(self, X):
    X = np.matrix(X)
    m, n = X.shape
    X = np.c_[np.matrix(np.ones((m, 1))), X]
    z=X*self.w_
    phi=self.sigFunc(z)
    return self.decide(phi)

def decide(self, x):
    return np.where(x >= 0.5, 1, 0)

def costfunc(self, X):
    z = X * self.w_
    phi =self.sigFunc(z)
    J = -y.T * np.log(phi) - (np.ones((m, 1)) - y).T * np.log(np.ones((m, 1)) - phi)
    return J

def fit(self, X, y):
    X = np.matrix(X).T
    m, n = X.shape
    print "the number of futures is %d" %n
    X = np.c_[np.matrix(np.ones((m, 1))), X]
    y = np.matrix(y).T
    self.w_ = np.matrix(np.zeros((n + 1, 1)))
    for xi, yi in zip(X, y):
        zi = xi * self.w_
        phii = self.sigFunc(zi)
        gradJi = -xi.T * (yi - phii)
        self.w_ -=  self.eta * gradJi
        self.eta *= 0.1
    print "final parameter is (%d, %d)" %(self.w_[0], self.w_[1])
    z = X * self.w_
    phi =self.sigFunc(z)
    correctAnswer = np.where(np.array(y == self.decide(phi)) == True, 1, 0)
    return float(sum(correctAnswer)) / len(correctAnswer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit. The fitting is now solved in two ways: as a simple gradient descent and by means of the scipy optimizer. The gradient descent is very slow and should not be used for real problems. I tested the class on the data taken from the Machine Learning course at [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)

I'm not sure I can share the original data set. Here is a short fragment of it:

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
```

Here are the outputs of two solutions:

**Simple gradient descent** (after 100000 iterations...)

```
Number of Features: 3
Found Solution:
[[-4.81180027]
 [ 0.04528064]
 [ 0.03819149]]
Train Accuracy: 0.910000
```

**Scipy Optimizer** (very quickly)

```
Number of Features: 3
Found Solution:
[[-25.16131869]
 [  0.20623159]
 [  0.20147149]]
Train Accuracy: 0.890000
```

The decision boundary in this code works only for the same type of the problem (a straight line separating two sets). For a better accuracy you can try to involve combinations of the features as new features (be aware of a possible overfitting).

[image: Logistic regression Decision boundary as a straight line separating two sets]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import scipy.optimize as op
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Logisticr():

    def __init__(self, X, y, alg, eta, w):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.alg = alg
        self.eta = eta
        self.w = w
        self.m, self.n = np.shape(X)

    def sigFunc(self, z):
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp( -z ))

    def decide(self, x):
        return np.where(x >= 0.5, 1, 0)

    def costfunc(self, w, X, y):

        w = w.reshape((self.n,1))
        z = X * w
        phi =self.sigFunc(z)

        # calculating the cost function
        part1 = np.multiply(y, np.log(phi))
        part2 = np.multiply((1 - y), np.log(1 - phi))

        J = (-part1 - part2).sum()/self.m

        # calculating the gradient
        grad = X.T * (phi - y) / self.m        

        return J, grad    

    def graddescent(self, maxiter):

        for i in range(0, maxiter):
            J, grad = self.costfunc(self.w, self.X, self.y)
            self.w = self.w - self.eta*grad

        return self.w

    def fit(self):

        print "Number of Features: %d" %self.n

        if self.alg == 0:
            _maxiter = 100000
            self.w = self.graddescent(_maxiter)
        else:
            Result = op.minimize(fun = self.costfunc, 
                                 x0 = self.w, 
                                 args = (self.X, self.y),
                                 method = 'TNC',
                                 jac = True);

            self.w = Result.x
            self.w = np.matrix(self.w).T

        print "Found Solution:" 
        print self.w

        z = self.X * self.w
        phi = self.sigFunc(z)
        correctAnswer = np.where(np.array(self.y == self.decide(phi)) == True, 1, 0)

        accuracy = float(sum(correctAnswer)) / len(correctAnswer)

        print "Train Accuracy: %f" %accuracy

    def plot(self):

        if self.n == 3:
            ind_1 = np.where(self.y == 1)
            ind_0 = np.where(self.y == 0)

            x1_1 = self.X[:, [1]].min()
            x1_2 = self.X[:, [1]].max()

            x2_1 = -(self.w[0, 0] + self.w[1, 0]*x1_1)/self.w[2, 0]
            x2_2 = -(self.w[0, 0] + self.w[1, 0]*x1_2)/self.w[2, 0]

            plt.plot(self.X[ind_1, [1]], self.X[ind_1, [2]], "bo", markersize=3)
            plt.plot(self.X[ind_0, [1]], self.X[ind_0, [2]], "ro", markersize=3)

            plt.plot([x1_1, x1_2], [x2_1, x2_2], "g-")

            plt.xlabel("Feature 1")
            plt.ylabel("Feature 2")
            plt.title("Decision boundary")
            plt.show()

        return 1

# Main module
_f = loadtxt('data/ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',')

_X, _y = _f[:,[0,1]], _f[:,[2]]

_m = np.shape(_X)[0]

# add a column of 1
_X = np.hstack((np.matrix(np.ones((_m, 1))),_X))
_y = np.matrix(_y)

_alg = 1   # 0 = using simple gradient descent
           # 1 = using an optimizer

_eta = 0.001  # initial eta value for _type = 0

_n= np.shape(_X)[1]

_w = np.matrix(np.zeros((_n, 1)))

# creating an instance of the Logisticr        
lr = Logisticr(_X, _y, _alg, _eta, _w);
lr.fit()
lr.plot()
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to work with the referenced data set. It looks for me like the classes are not good separable using only Temperature and Humidity. Even if you use the high order feature combinations you will probably overfit the classifier. Don't you think so?

[image: Not separable classes using logistic regression]

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it with my dataset and got the 70 parcent accuracy.

Comment: With which algorithm? Did you try both of them?

Comment: To begin with, I used gradient descent. However, I cannot plot and the accuracy is 70 percent so I am going to verify the validity by using cross-validation. I give you my blog. http://kiwamizamurai.blogspot.com/2018/04/implementation-of-logistic-regression.html

Comment: I will try to use the dataset from your blog. It will be difficult to plot the decision boundary having so many features and their combinations.

Comment: I used two features,humidity and temperature. So I can plot the decision boundary. Is that incorrect?

Comment: it should work if they are good separable. did you involved combinations of the two features? sorry I have not analyzed your code yet.

Comment: Yes, I did. OK. I will apreciate that if you try to use the dataset from my blog and analyse it.

Comment: I updated my post. I think the data set is not good separable based on the Temp and Humid.

Comment: I agree with your idea, but when I used the library of scikit-learn to logistic regression, I got 99 parcent accuracy with all features except for date. Didn't you describe decision boundary? In addition, I could not plot the data.

Comment: The data set is indeed good separable using all the features (even Temperature and Light seem to be enough for a good boundary). It depends on what you want to achieve. What is your purpose?

Comment: My purpose is to implement logistic regression. At the first, I ran the code with two features to check whether my code is correct or not. So if it is correct, I will do the same process with all features and understand logistic regression.